# ios9, game center not showing completion banners

Tags: ios9, sandbox, game-center

I have a game in sandbox mode for Game Centre.  I got the achievement completion banners working a long time ago in my code, haven't touched that stuff.. but yesterday I noticed that banners weren't showing up when I completed achievements.

I poured through code, couldn't find anything wrong.  googled, couldn't find anything useful.

I came to the conclusion after hours wasted, that there must be something wrong with Game Center and it would probably be fixed by the morning.
Well, it still doesn't seem to show banners!

Note that - Achievements that are unlocked do show up as completed in the Game Center view.  so the report is getting through.

Also - i noticed that when completing a challenge, the banner does appear.  Just not when achievements are completed.

anyway - my question is - could there be something in the sandbox of game center server that is causing this problem ?   Before I waste another day ripping my code apart i'd like to be sure it is my problem !!!

thanks.

Comment: **version note** Game Center will be removed in iOS 10.

Comment: but the backend service will still be there as i understand it ?

Comment: update - i didn't change my code and now the banners are appearing again... must have been a server side problem !